# Windows 10 2+ minute boot SSD

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

Some few months ago boot times went crazy slow so I debugged it alot and tried dozen fixes and what-not but still no success.

I saw that printer drivers were getting hung up so I removed them as well, for the life of me I cannot see what's causing the slowness.

Also, I have tried booting in safe mode same happens, what I noticed is as soon as the initial boot is done, my keyboard and mouse loose power and stop shining, when the power-shine returns the windows welcome screen shows up some few seconds after.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Analyzer trace:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=18zxZSpDEYuAa75meCNh8sVEBWpa2Skoj

Comment: Disable fast boot. Make sure your drivers work fine such as video card, network card. Reinstall or update them from the official website of the manufacturer. Update your BIOS. Also I suggest that you could disable Windows Update service temporarily.
If nothing there a clean install of windows might be your only option.

Answer (score 0):

With all the weird things happening, it would not be a surprise if there is something with the OS, and a clean install would not hurt to try. If you do this route, save all your files to another storage location like in the cloud, or external drive. If you do not have access to another computer for during the process, I would download all the drivers for your computer to a flash drive, mostly your wifi and Ethernet drivers.

If you are not familiar with the entire process, you will need to make a bootable usb by downloading a Windows 10 iso file which can be downloaded here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 . If your bios is legacy only and and not uefi and there is not an option to enable uefi, you will need to use software to create a bootable usb like this https://rufus.ie/en_IE.html. If your bios is uefi, you can use the windows media creation tool that you downloaded from Microsoft.

Comment: Yeah, I'd avoid the clean install as that is always a last-option route.

Comment: @soldatinconnu Depends who you ask. I work in IT and for us time is valuable and most times than not, a fresh OS install fixes the issues, and it is a lot faster than troubleshooting an issue that will end up leading to a clean install. If you would like to help him troubleshoot all the issues, issue by issue, and step by step, go ahead. That is my recommendation by reading all the issues he is having though.